# Property must be initialized before being accessed, is initialized in the mount function in Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Calendar component where I need to change the date on the frontend. The Calendar is generated on the server and the HTML is sent to Blade.

I initialize the Calendar in the `mount()` function and I expect it to stay initialized. However, when I update the "date" field, I get the error: `Typed property App\Http\Livewire\Directory\Events\Calendar::$calendar must not be accessed before initialization`

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Directory\Events;

use App\Services\Calendar as ServicesCalendar;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Livewire\Component;

class Calendar extends Component
{

    protected ServicesCalendar $calendar;
    public string $string_calendar;
    public Collection $events;
    public $date;

    public function mount() {
        $this->date = now();
        $this->calendar = new ServicesCalendar($this->date);
        foreach($this->events as $event) {
            $this->calendar->add_event($event->title, Carbon::parse($event->begins_at)->toDateString());
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->calendar->setDate($this->date);
        $this->string_calendar = (string) $this->calendar;
        return view('livewire.directory.events.calendar');
    }
}
```

Here is my Livewire component:

```
<div>
    <div class="flex flex-row">
        <input type="month" class="input" wire:model="date" />
    </div>
    {!! $string_calendar !!}
</div>
```

Comment: The field must be public, not private/ protected - or you need to rehydate it manually.

Comment: @Qirel I can't put it in public, how would I hydrate it manually?